# How would I get updated position after passing object through event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on putting together a point and click game and I need to get the updated position of a moving gameobject in a scene. I'm currently passing the object that is selected with the mouse through an event to another script after the object is clicked on. The object's position is stored from when the object is clicked on, not it's current location, I would like to pass this into the update loop somehow to get an updated position.

I've looked at using member variables to get updates from the update function, but that just seems messy.
Is there a better solution for this or should I just use member variables?

Thanks!

here is the code I'm concerned with

```
    void Start()
    {
        RegisterForMouseEvents();
    }

    private void RegisterForMouseEvents()
    {
        var cameraRaycaster = FindObjectOfType<CameraRaycaster>();
        cameraRaycaster.onMouseOverEnemy += OnMouseOverEnemy;
    }

    void OnMouseOverEnemy(EnemyAI enemy)
    {
     // enemy is object passed from delegate
     // that has the EnemyAI script attached.
     // how do I pass enemy into Update() then either 
     // back into this method or another method?
    }
```

Comment: Will `GameObject.Find("name").transform.position` solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would make it function, but I am trying to figure out how to get use out of reference passed by the delegate. I'm wanting to have it be more dynamic and not reliant on the specific object name, since I would like to add NPCs and things later on that might not have the same name.

Comment: "I am trying to figure out how to get use out of reference passed by the delegate" can you explain what you mean in a bit more detail?

Comment: posting some example code might make your question clearer too

Comment: You could `Add` them to a `List` when they register and in the `Update` function run through the list (`foreach( EnemyAI enemy in enemyList){...}`)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, that's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a local variable.

```
private EnemyAI myEnemy;

void Start()
{
    RegisterForMouseEvents();
}

private void RegisterForMouseEvents()
{
    var cameraRaycaster = FindObjectOfType<CameraRaycaster>();
    cameraRaycaster.onMouseOverEnemy += OnMouseOverEnemy;
}

void OnMouseOverEnemy(EnemyAI enemy)
{
    myEnemy = enemy;
}

void Update(){
    //log position
    print(myEnemy.transform.position);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking originally. I was just thinking that there might be a better way, I'll probably just end up doing something similar. Thanks!